# Why the solution $u(x)$ of $-\Delta u+u=g(u)$ is $O(e^{-a|x|})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

I have some problems when I read the paper ["Symmetry of Positive Solutions of Nonlinear Elliptic Equations in $\mathbb{R}^N$"](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjqoJqyzLz8AhVaCYgKHXQ-BlMQFnoECAwQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmath.osu.edu%2F%7Elam.184%2Fpaper%2Fgnn1981.pdf&usg=AOvVaw01MDW2tc1j-CFkOvLzJskh)

The equation (1.3) is $-\Delta u+m^2u=g(u)\quad\text{in} \mathbb{R}^n,\quad n\geq2,m>0$. In the following discusstion, we always assume $m=1$

My problems are from the proof of proposition 4.1

1. After $h(r)=O(e^{-ar})$ is obtained, why $$\int_{|x-y|<1}|f(y)|dy=O(e^{-a|x|})$$
   it seems that $f(y)=-\Delta u(y)$.
2. How to obtain formular (4.6).
   From the former formular, we can obtain $$\int_{|x-y|<1}|\Delta u|dy=O(e^{-a|x|})$$. It seems that $$\int_{|x-y|<1} u dy=O(e^{-a|x|})$$
3. What is the "standard interior estimates" used after (4.6).
   I know that if $Lu=-\sum_{i,j=1}^n(a^{ij}(x)u_{x_i})_{x_j}+\sum_{i=1}^nb^i(x)u_{x_i}+c(x)u$ and  $a^{ij}\in C^1(U),b^i,c\in L^\infty(U)$ and $f\in L^2(U)$, the weak solution $u\in H^1(U)$ of $Lu=f$ is $u\in H_{loc}^2(U)$, and for each open $V\subset\subset U$, we have $||u||_{H^2(V)}\leq C(||f||_{L^2}+||u||_{L^2})$.
   Is this the "standard interior estimates"?
4. Why $$\left(\int_{|x-y|<3/4} u^pdy\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}=O(e^{-a|x|}),\quad p=\frac{n}{n-2}$$
   It seems that Sobolev embedding is used. But we seem to prove that $||u||_{W^{2,1}(B^0(x,3/4))}=O(e^{-a|x|})$
   and whyWhy $$\left(\int_{|x-y|<3/4} |\Delta u|^pdy\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}=O(e^{-a|x|})$$
5. How is the "interior estimates" used again to get $$\left(\int_{|x-y|<1/2} u^qdy\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}\subset O(e^{-a|x|}),\quad q=\frac{np}{n-2p}$$
   and what does the notation $\subset$ mean.
6. How does the formular $u(x)=O(e^{-a|x|})$ obtain.

I would be very grateful if you could help me.

---

[image]
[image]